# Getting a .sh to start on login / boot / startup

Tags: scripts, login, browser, autostart

I think I'm starting to go mad. I have tried several things by now, and nothing works.

This is on an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop Version.

I tried this guide:
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/run-script-on-startup

My script file is a quite simple, start chromium-browser in kiosk mode with this IP / page.

```
chromium-browser -kiosk -incognito https://google.com
```

Saved this file as tiles.sh in /usr/local/
Then I chmod +x tiles.sh

First option I have tried:
crontab -e | where I added:

```
@reboot root /usr/local/tiles.sh
```

2nd thing I tried was to add it to .profile in the home folder on the bottom line. Nothing...

```
sh /usr/local/tiles.sh
```

I have then tried to use Ubuntu's built in "Startup Application Preferences", again nothing...
https://itsfoss.com/manage-startup-applications-ubuntu/

```
Name; Tiles, Path: /usr/local/tiles.sh, I didn't add any comments.
```

4th thing was with a tiles.service added to the systemctl

```
[Unit]
description=Tiles
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/local/tiles.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/tiles.service

systemctl enable tiles.service

systemctl start tiles.service

reboot

---

So, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit:

- So I fixed a copy-paste error with missing /, so the path looked incomplete
- A comment suggested that 'crontab -e' is only for 'on boot' stuff, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: You need an absolute path to your script, then Startup Applications should work just fine.

Comment: Please avoid commenting on your own question. To add new information or update, please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1491716/edit) instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: The approaches are wrong. A GUI program can only be started with the GUI running / having the desktop available. systemd units start too early. Recommendation is to create a .desktop file which is executed by the desktop environment once its started.

Comment: You should post your solution as an "answer" below and press a checkmark next to it. Don't add "solved" to the title and don't edit the question with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Cron has [its own PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401621/22222), which is hard coded and set to:

```
/usr/bin:/bin
```

This means that only programs installed in those two directories can be launched by name through cron. Firefox is installed at `/usr/bin/firefox`, so `firefox` is enough for cron to find it, but chromium is installed as a snap package and is most likely at `/snap/bin/chromium`. This means your script can't find it as `chromium` and instead needs the full path. It should work if you change your script to:

```
/snap/bin/chromium-browser -kiosk -incognito https://google.com
```

In general, you can run `type command` to find the path to a command. So `type chromium-browser` will give you the path to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to `sudo apt purge chromium-browser -y` and switch to firefox